# Distributing executable terminal commands on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, terminal

I make bash/ruby commands for basically everything in my development workflow (`todo`, `pullrequest`, `asciiart`, `remind` and so on). People I work with always ask me to share my commands with them, but to do this, I transfer the files to their computer, then `xargs` through each file with `chmod +x` and `mv /usr/local/bin`.

Wondering what work I can do upfront to make the import process easier. Fine with some Mac installer tool, or a git & makefile solution, but I'd really like to get the process down to a single click or command if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use Nix expressions with Nix package manager: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nix_package_manager ! It is supported on Macs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a Terminal command executable by just selecting it in Finder and pressing the keyboard shortcut.

Below is the method for solving your problem.

**1. Create a macOS service using Automator**

1.1 Open Automator and create a new service
1.2 At the top, choose *Service receives selected `no input` in `Finder`*
1.3 Drag *Get Selected Finder Items* action to the workflow
1.4 Drag *Run Shell Script* action to the workflow
1.5 In *Run Shell Script* action, select *Pass input: `as arguments`* and in the text field, type:
`chmod u+x "$@" && mv "$@" /usr/local/bin`
1.6 Save service

[image: automator workflow]

**2. Distribute service to colleagues’ computers**

2.1 The created service is located in `~/Library/Services`
2.2 Move it to other computers and install it by opening the file, or manually copying the service to `~/Library/Services`

[image: service installer]

**3. Bind service to a keyboard shortcut**

3.1 Open *System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Services → General*
3.2 Choose an appropriate keyboard shortcut for your service

You can also run the service by right-clicking on file and selecting the action in Services submenu at the bottom of contextual menu.

Comment: Screenshots and effort appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Share a **Dropbox** directory with them that contains your scripts, and ensure that it is in their `PATH`.

No updates are necessary when you improve your scripts as they will automatically see the latest version.

Manage the directory with `git` for version control.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd post the standard makefile solution for completion sake. Works for macOS/ and GNU(Linux)

Put a makefile in the project directory.

So the directory looks like `[ my-executable` `makefile` `readme.md ]` or whatever

```
# makefile

install: 

    # side note: `@` prevents make from printing the command itself

    @echo "installing..."
    @chmod +x my-executable
    @cp my-executable /usr/local/bin
    @echo "done!"
```

then inform recipients to download/clone and run `sudo make install` from the project directory

Or for a one-line solution (presuming the recipients trust you a little too much)

```
git clone https://githost.com/myaccount/myrepo.git && 
sudo make install -C myrepo && 
rm -rf myrepo
```

(download, install, remove cloned directory) – user 16 mins ago

Comment: One line `git clone https://githost.com/myaccount/myrepo.git && sudo make install -C myrepo && rm -rf myrepo`" (download, install, remove cloned directory)